# Androidhwext Is it a System/Vendor App or Third Party App

Tags: huawei

Is the Android App `Androidhwext` part of the Android System or Huawei Standard apps or is it a third party app?

I am concerned its a virus app due to the amount of permissions it asks for. I am unable to uninstall it but this may suggest its a system app?

Comment: Even if it's a malware I would say Huawei deliberately chose to add it in your device. You're not the only one who has it. https://www.google.co.in/search?q="Androidhwext"